# Sqoop list-tables issue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using the Hortonworks Sandbox 2.2 VM and am having issues when running Sqoop against oracle. I'm executing the command like:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydbhost.com:1521/sid --username user --password password
```

It executes, but nothing happens:

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/05/29 15:55:58 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.2.2.4.2-2
15/05/29 15:55:58 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/05/29 15:55:58 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
15/05/29 15:55:58 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.4.2-2-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/05/29 15:55:59 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
```

If I specify --driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver as a parameter, then the list-tables command works fine, but the import fails with the error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". I read in several places that specifying the --driver argument is not the right way to go about things, but when I don't specify it I can't get anything to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps
  1. placed ojdbc6.jar in $SQOOP_HOME/lib 
  2. removed the --driver option 
  3. quoted all the parameters

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gopikrishna_BD anwser, Oracle db stores table names in uppercase by defalut. So while doing sqoop import, give the table name in uppercase. You should also give the database name in uppercase.

This [article](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/10891.transferring-bulk-data-between-oracle-database-and-hadoop-ecosystem-with-sqoop.aspx) will help you to learn more about Sqoop with Oracle.